# How to make Local Pickup method be chosen based on cart total in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I want to make local pickup shipping method be chosen with radio input based on the cart total. I used this code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_modify_shipping_methods', 10, 2);
function custom_modify_shipping_methods($rates, $package) {
    // Get the cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Set the threshold for choosing the local pickup shipping method
    $threshold_amount = 2500;

    // Check if the cart total is less than the threshold
    if ($cart_total < $threshold_amount) {
        // Loop through shipping rates
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            // Check if it's a local pickup method
            if (strpos($rate_id, 'local_pickup') !== false) {
                // Set the cost to zero (free)
                $rates[$rate_id]->cost = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

This code unset all shipping methods, it shows local pick up label not the radio type input. The input type is hidden and I can not proceed to payment as the shipping method is not selected. How can I modify the code to make local pick up method default chosen others unset if the cart total is less than 2500?

Answer (score 0):

When there is only one available shipping method, the corresponding radio input button is hidden and this available shipping method is automatically selected by WooCommerce…

The code that you are using is not adapted to your needs. Instead, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_shipping_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function filter_shipping_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    $threshold_amount = 2500; // Here set the threshold amount
    $cart_subtotal    = $package['cart_subtotal']; // Or use $package['contents_cost'] for excluding taxes

    // If cart items subtotal is up to the defined threshold amount
    if ( $cart_subtotal >= $threshold_amount ) {
        // Loop through shipping rates for the current shipping package
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // Targeting local pickup
            if( 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $taxes = array(); // Initializing variable

                // Loop through tax costs
                foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax) {
                    $taxes[$key] = 0; // Set tax cost to zero
                }
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0; // Set cost to zero
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes; // Set back taxes costs array
            } else {
                unset($rates[$rate_key]); // Remove other rates
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**Always empty your cart, to refresh cached shipping data.**

---

###### Additional note:

As your question is not so clear, maybe you want Local pickup to be the only available shipping method **if the subtotal is below 2500**… In that case, you will have simply to replace:

```php
if ( $cart_subtotal >= $threshold_amount ) {
```

with:

```php
if ( $cart_subtotal < $threshold_amount ) {
```

Comment: This code shows all shipping methods. It does not unset flat rate and makes local pickup is not chosen.

Comment: @RobertZalinyan For me the code work perfectly… Now maybe **your question is not so clear**, as my answer code make local pickup the only available shipping method **once subtotal has reached 2500** *(`$subtotal_amount >= $threshold_amount`)*… Your code was making the contrary  *(`$subtotal_amount < $threshold_amount`)*.