# Set Local pick up cost to zero when Free shipping is available in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, minimum, shipping-method

I offer free shipping for €45. I have hidden the other shipping methods, except local pick-up, when free is available using the code below.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_except_local_when_free_is_available', 100 );
function hide_shipping_except_local_when_free_is_available($rates) {
    $free = $local = array();

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
        } elseif ( 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $local[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? array_merge( $free, $local ) : $rates;
}
```

My problem here is that Local pick-up must be free when cart subtotal is up to €45, so the customer must be able to choose between 2 free options (free shipping or local pick-up free) when free shipping is available or choose between paid shipping options.

I can't find the way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To offer also **free local pickup** when free shipping is available *(keeping other shipping methods hidden)*, try to use the following code replacement *(commented)*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 100, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    $free = array(); // Initializing variable

    // 1st Loop (free shipping): Loop through shipping rates for the current shipping package
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[$rate_key] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }

    // 2nd Loop (local pickup): Loop through shipping rates for the current shipping package
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // Set 'local_pickup' cost to zero when free shipping is available
        if ( 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id && ! empty($free) ) {
            $taxes = array(); // Initializing variable

            // Loop through tax costs
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax) {
                $taxes[$key] = 0; // Set tax cost to zero
            }
            $rate->cost = 0; // Set cost to zero
            $rate->taxes = $taxes; // Set back taxes costs array
            $free[$rate_key] = $rate; // Set this rate into the $free array
            break; // Remove this, if there is more than 1 Local pickup option for a shipping Zone
        }
    }
    return ! empty($free) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

**Important:** You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping method cache.

Other related threads:

- [How to make Local Pickup method be chosen based on cart total in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769694/how-to-make-local-pickup-method-be-chosen-based-on-cart-total-in-woocommerce/77771864#77771864)
- [WooCommerce: Hide other shipping methods except local pickup when free shipping is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400762/woocommerce-hide-other-shipping-methods-except-local-pickup-when-free-shipping/66400924#66400924)